# How to update variable in closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, chartist.js

Okay, so there is a charting library called [ChartistJS](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js). I am using a plugin in it called [Axistitle plugin](https://github.com/alexstanbury/chartist-plugin-axistitle) to show axisTitle. I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vM9paTGsDrhoN9Kr2qOn?p=preview) to highlight the issue. Now the issue is that when I open the dropdown I want to see different Axis title based on the options that I select. Sounds simple enough.

Now if you go to the source code of `chartist-plugin-axistitle.js` On line   44 and 49 you will find two `console.logs(options)`. Now open developers console,clear the console and select the option distance from the dropdown. You will see two console.log() from line 44 and 49. Now look at the variable `axisY.axistitle` on line 44 and `axisY.axistitle` on line 49. Look different?? One must be `Distance(km)` on line 44 which is the expected value and the one on line 49 will be `Unit`. Why? The value in the line above is changed to `Distance(km)`, it's still `Unit`? It is getting executed and printed but why the function is not taking the updated value? I smell it is something to do with closure? How would I solve this? How can I get the updated value of options in it?

Help is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

as I am supposed to give some minimalistic code here.

```
Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle = function(options) {

    options = Chartist.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
    console.log(options); // I get updated values
    console.log("I am printed everytime too. Because I am supposed too.");
    return function ctAxisTitle(chart) {
        console.log("I will get printed first time but not subsequent times. I don't know why?");
        chart.on('created', function(data) {
            console.log("I am printed every time as chart is re-rendered/created every time it is updated");
console.log(options); //Should be closure of above value. But I won't take updated options value. I'll stick with the one I was initialized with. Coz I am stupid.
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code here in your question. Try to make an example that reproduces your problem that is minimal and complete.

Comment: @SteveH. added as per request

Comment: use a different name between the argument `options` and the result of the `extend`.

Comment: @DavinTryon It doesn't work. [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vM9paTGsDrhoN9Kr2qOn?p=preview) is the proof

Comment: You already have a clue where you print "I don't know why"...  Check this : https://plnkr.co/edit/RQusKVX5d9Y5w4Lje7DH?p=preview

Comment: Hey, @SteveH. Could you elaborate more on that, It works, but how?